# Can you hijack a boat that's being driven?

Tags: watch-dogs

Sometimes I find myself catapulted into the middle of the river. Thankfully, passing boats usually stop and I can climb onto the boat.

However, I cannot find any way of stealing the boat that's being driven, except to shoot the poor driver who happened to be in the wrong place at the wrong time.

Is there any way to hijack an occupied boat, the same way you can hijack an occupied car?

Comment: I have only been able to "hijack" boats in watch_dogs by killing the occupants.

Comment: Likewise, only killing them worked for me. I haven't tried this, but the only thing I can think of is shooting around them or the boat itself and seeing if they abandon ship. I'm not sure if they even do this on land, let alone water.

Comment: @Lyrical If you are referring to cars on land, the drivers will jump out of their car if you fire an unsilenced weapon.  I unloaded my spec-ops goblin into a car til it was smoking and the woman inside was still begging me not to use the gun. One shot of an unsilenced pistol and she was heading for the hills. Seems buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the only ways to hijack a boat at this point in time is to kill the driver or if you can manage to climb aboard the boat,

> If you shoot near the driver, they will often get out of the driver's seat and cower on the ground. You can then drive without killing them. - answer by zach

I have tried testing this including using all the craftable objects and can't find another way round it.

Comment: Not correct, firing a shotgun next to the driver will make them get out of the driver's seat.  Zach's answer is correct.

Comment: it is correct because for that to work you need to be on the boat which is mighty hard to do when its moving and your in the water

Comment: Yes, but read the question.  *Thankfully, passing boats usually stop and I can climb onto the boat.*

Comment: have edited the answer to include zachs answer although i would say this doesnt work 100% of the time - I have done this once or twice by accident and they sped off.

Comment: Seems you may get away with just aiming at them

Answer (score 3):

If you shoot near the driver, they will often get out of the driver's seat and cower on the ground. You can then drive without killing them.